# Using variable from option in the next function

Tags: javascript, html-select

I try to solve problem with getting values from option.
When I choose one number from select the number is printing correctly in p tag and let index is also correct, but I want to  use 'const n' in the next function in this program. Just for testing I create function send() to check, do I can use this variable but all time console.log is NaN. How Can I solve this?

```
<p id="p">Your number is: 0</p>

<select id="select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<button onclick="send();">SEND</button>


//JS
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
    var pElem = document.getElementById('p')


const n = selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let index = selectElem.value;

  pElem.innerHTML = 'Your number is: ' + index;
  return index;

})

console.log(n);
const a  = n*2;
function send(){
  console.log('-----');
  console.log(n);
  console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: You can't access the variables inside the function scope. For that, you have to create a class, that should hold all variables and the required functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function setN and cal it to update object.n.. See my example

```js
//JS
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
    var pElem = document.getElementById('p')

  var obj ={
    n:'weqwe'
    }
   function setN(n){ 
     obj.n =n
  }
 selectElem.addEventListener('change', function(obj) {
  let index = selectElem.value;

  setN( selectElem.value);
  pElem.innerHTML = 'Your number is: ' + index;
  return index;

})
     
  function send(){
    
    console.log(obj.n)
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p">Your number is: 0</p>

<select id="select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<button onclick="send();">SEND</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,the second parameter (the function) is a callback.
ALso, you can use `window`,to get desired objects

```
var a=10
function send(){
 console.log('-----');
 console.log(window.n);
 console.log(window.a);
}
```

also , JS is prototype based language .So, I doubt that it has anything to do with `classes` . (Syntactically,yeah maybe)